# Convert flat file to a different format using shell or python

Tags: python, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have a file in the below format:

```
User: user1
Count:3
Sum:80
  departmentId: dept1
  Amount by departmentId: 20
  departmentId: dept1
  Amount by departmentId: 35
  departmentId: dept2
  Amount by departmentId: 25
User: user2
Count:3
Sum:7.199999999999999
  departmentId: dept1
  Amount by departmentId: 2.4
  departmentId: dept2
  Amount by departmentId: 2.4
  departmentId: dept3
  Amount by departmentId: 2.4
User: user3
Count:1
Sum:0.2
  departmentId: dept2
  Amount by departmentId: 0.2
User: user4
Count:2
Sum:2
  departmentId: dept3
  Amount by departmentId: 1
  departmentId: dept3
  Amount by departmentId: 1
```

The file list basically the User dues for a department. If the same user is due to a department multiple times then that need to be merged into one row. The output file needs to be in the below format.

EDIT: For user1, he has 2 dues for dept1 and 1 due for dept2. So in the output file the 2 dues for dept1 need to be merged into 1 and the total count on line will be 2, as count needs to be user per department.

```
Format:
count total_sum
userId+deptId sum for that dept

Example:

2 80
user1dept1 55
user1dept2 25
3 7.2
user2dept1 2.4
user2dept2 2.4
user2dept3 2.4
1 0.2
user3dept2 0.2
1 2
user4dept3 2
```

Please advice on which scripting language to use, bash or python?And how to loop through the input file? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: To be frank, am not sure how to go about it, not sure to use shell or python here. Am new to scripting. I am looking for ideas. I think i need to loop through each "User" in the input file.

Comment: Why did the count change from 3 to 2 for your first output line? Please make sure the output you posted is **exactly** what you'd want to get from the input you posted.

Comment: @EdMorton The count changed because for user1 there are 2 dues for the same dept1. These 2 dues need to be merged into 1. And the user1 has 1 due for dept3. So total count is 2, count is by user per dept.

Comment: What uses either of these formats? Consider whether translating data on one non-standard format to another non-standard format is a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use a shell to manipulate text (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for some of the reasons why). Awk is the tool that the guys who invented shell invented for shell to call to manipulate text so just use that.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=": *" }
{
    gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")
    f[$1] = $2
}
/Amount/ {
    dept = f["departmentId"]
    subTot[dept] += $2
    tot += $2
}
$1 == "User" {
    if (NR>1) {
        prt()
    }
    user = $2
}
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    print length(subTot), tot
    for (dept in subTot) {
        print user dept, subTot[dept]
    }
    delete subTot
    tot = 0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2 80
user1dept1 55
user1dept2 25
3 7.2
user2dept1 2.4
user2dept2 2.4
user2dept3 2.4
1 0.2
user3dept2 0.2
1 2
user4dept3 2
```

The above assumes you have an awk where `length(array)` gives you the number of elements in an array. If you don't then just count every time you see a new dept for the current user (e.g. by using `if (!(dept in subTot)) numDepts++` just before you populate `subTot[dept]`) and print that value instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, AWK is the way to go i think. One quick question, in the awk script, in the output i see that user's are misplaced. The first one needs to be user1dept1 with the sum of 80

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton. Looking into AWK and it is awesome. So, with AWK how do we give fixed length? Say in this case for the output, for the first line which has a count of 2 followed by sum of 80, if i want this count field to have a fixed length of 5 and followed by 80?

Comment: @MaverickRiz I'm not sure if you're asking about fixed width input fields or fixed width output fields or something else but one interpretation would be `printf "%5d%d\n", length(subTot), tot`.

Comment: I meant fixed width output fields starting. Example:For output in Line 1, count is fixed length of 5 starting at 1st position, then sum is length of 11, starting at 6th position and 2 decimals

Comment: `printf "%5d%11d\n", length(subTot), tot`? You can see the syntax from those examples - try it and ask if you can;t get it to do what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170164/discussion-between-maverick-riz-and-ed-morton).

Comment: This was working fine on my machine, but when i was trying to run on a different box i ran into an issue. "fatal: attempt to use scalar `subTot' as an array". Kindly advice. Thanks

Comment: Your input file contained no "Amount" lines or you copy/pasted the script wrong.